# Jquery Traverse Ancestors for input fields

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I am trying to write a function that will grab the 2 input fields in the div and push them to an array which I will post as JSON.  I am having trouble traversing the div to find the value of the 2nd input field.  I have a function that will allow the client to add more rows(div class = row id="addInput").

HTML:

```
<div class="testList" id = wrapper>
<div class="row" id="addInput" >
    <section class="col col-4">
         <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
            <input type="date" class="ptoDate" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="Request Date">
         </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-2">
        <label class="input"><i class="icon-append fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            <input class="ptoHours" min="0" max="8" type="number" name="hour" id="hour" placeholder="Hours">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-2">
        <a id="addField" title="Add More Fields" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addInput('wrapper');">&nbsp;+&nbsp;</a>
    </section>
</div>
```

JS: It appears that since I have sections and labels, siblings isnt the way to go.

```
var timeoffRequests = [];

$("input[class = ptoDate]").each(function(){

    var date = $(this).val();
    var hours = $(this).siblings('.ptoHours').val();

    item ={};
    item['date'] = date;
    item['hours'] = hours;

    timeoffRequests.push(item);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements **ptoHours** and **ptoDate** are not siblings, but both are descendent of your row div.

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) in order to find the parent row and then you can find your ptoHours element:

```js
var timeoffRequests = [];

$(".ptoDate").each(function(idx, ele){

    var date = $(ele).val();;
    var hours = $(ele).closest('.row').find('.ptoHours').val();

    item ={};
    item['date'] = date;
    item['hours'] = hours;

    timeoffRequests.push(item);
})



console.log(timeoffRequests);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="testList" id=wrapper>
    <div class="row" id="addInput">
        <section class="col col-4">
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                <input type="date" class="ptoDate" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="Request Date">
            </label>
        </section>
        <section class="col col-2">
            <label class="input"><i class="icon-append fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                <input class="ptoHours" min="0" max="8" type="number" name="hour" id="hour" placeholder="Hours">
            </label>
        </section>
        <section class="col col-2">
            <a id="addField" title="Add More Fields" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addInput('wrapper');">&nbsp;+&nbsp;</a>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow,Thanks! I should have looked at my own code and how I was handling the relationships.   I actually am dynamically removing any added  input rows by the $(this).closest('div').remove();